A new identity for the scalar triple product in $\mathbb{R}^3$
Using the determinant identity for the scalar triple product for $[(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}).\vec{c}]^2$ and factorizing using the quadruple scalar product identity $(\vec{p} \times \vec{q}).(\vec{r} \times \vec{s})$, I got the relation:
$$\left[ \vec{a} \vec{b} \vec{c} \right]^2 = (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}).\left((\vec{a}.\vec{a})(\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) + (\vec{a}.\vec{b})(\vec{c} \times \vec{a})+(\vec{a}.\vec{c})(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \right)$$
Is there any way of deriving this relation directly? I took a sort of roundabout way of doing it, converting the triple product into a determinant of dot products and then expanding it and factorizing it. Is it possible to somehow directly expand it into this form? Is this a well-known result (if so, what is it called) and is there any kind of nice interpretation to this result?
EDIT: I just recalled that $\left[\vec{a} \times \vec{b} \: \vec{b} \times \vec{c} \; \vec{c} \times \vec{a} \right]=[\vec{a} \, \vec{b} \, \vec{c}]^2$ but that doesn't seem to help.

I’ve never before seen nor used an identity like this. But you can argue that the expression has to be quadratic in each variable, symmetric under any permutation, and vanishes when the three vectors are linearly dependent (coplanar is the interesting case). Can you then argue your RHS must be correct up to a constant fwctor?

Uhh, I agree with the first and third thing but how do I argue it is quadratic and this is the only possible symmetric quadratic form?

What about using $|a\times b|=|a||b||\sin\angle( a,b)|$ and $|(a\times b)\cdot c|=|a\times b||c||\cos\angle (a\times b,c)|$? Then you get $$|(a\times b)\cdot c|=|a||b||c||\sin\angle (a,b)||\cos\angle (a\times b,c)|?$$

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin\lfloor}
$This can be derived with geometric algebra:
$$
  -(a\wedge b\wedge c)^2 = -[a\lcontr(a\wedge b\wedge c)\bigr]\cdot(b\wedge c) = -\bigl[(a\cdot a)(b\wedge c) - (a\cdot b)(a\wedge c) + (a\cdot c)(a\wedge b)\bigr]\cdot(b\wedge c).
$$
The expression $-(a\wedge b\wedge c)^2$ is the squared triple product, and the dot products like $-(a\wedge b)\cdot(b\wedge c)$ are the corresponding dot-products-of-cross-products $(a\times b)\cdot(b\times c)$.

The ideas behind this derivation are as follows (noting that the elements of a geometric algebra are called multivectors):

$J = a\wedge b\wedge c$ is a pseudoscalar. In 3D, pseudocalars commute with the whole algebra under the geometric product, i.e. $JX = XJ$ for all multivectors $X$.
That $-J^2$ is the squared triple product is a consequence of the triple product being the determinant. More generally, there is a unique pseudoscalar $I$ which is "right-handed" and has $I^2 = -1$; the determinant is then $JI^{-1}$, but $I^{-1} = -I$ so squaring gives $$(JI^{-1})^2 = -J^2II^{-1} = -J^2.$$
The wedge product $\wedge$ and left and right contractions $\lcontr$ and $\rcontr$ are dual under pseudoscalar multiplication. Specifically $$J(X\wedge Y) = (JX)\rcontr Y.$$ When the result of a contraction is a scalar the contractions are equal and symmetric in their arguments, so in this case I notate them with a dot $\cdot$. Together with the associativity of the wedge product we get the first step: $$-J(a\wedge b\wedge c) = -(aJ)\cdot(b\wedge c).\tag{Eq 1}$$ I also used the commutativity of $J$ here, though strictly this was unecessary.
For any multivector $X$, multiplication by a pseudoscalar is contraction, i.e. $XJ = X\lcontr J$. So now $$\text{(Eq 1)} = -(a\lcontr J)\cdot(b\wedge c).\tag{(Eq 2)}$$
Contraction by a vector is an antiderivation over wedge products, so $$a\lcontr(a\wedge b\wedge c) = (a\cdot a)(b\wedge c) - a\wedge[a\lcontr(b\wedge c)] = (a\cdot a)(b\wedge c) - (a\cdot b)(a\wedge c) + (a\cdot c)(a\wedge b).$$ The contraction dot between vectors is exactly the standard dot product. This was the third step, in total yielding the final expression $$\text{(Eq 2)} = -\bigl[(a\cdot a)(b\wedge c) - (a\cdot b)(a\wedge c) + (a\cdot c)(a\wedge b)\bigr]\cdot(b\wedge c).\tag{(Eq 3)}$$
For any vectors $a,b$ and $I$ the aformentioned right-handed unit pseudoscalar, $$a\times b = -(a\wedge b)I.$$ Using the duality from bullet (3) twice shows that $$(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d) = [(a\wedge b)I]\cdot[(c\wedge d)I] = \Bigl([I(a\wedge b)]\wedge(c\wedge d)\Bigr)I = I\Bigl([a\wedge b]\cdot[c\wedge d]\Bigr)I = -[a\wedge b]\cdot[c\wedge d].$$ Applying this to (Eq 3) gives the desired formula.


Sorry, I'm not really familiar with geometric algebra......I tried self-studying it and couldn't keep up, is there a way to convert your answer into something without $⌋$ and $∧$? Sorry for the crude language, clarifying, can this sort of logic be converted into vector notation in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

@Cognoscenti No, I don't think there's any simple way to convert this to standard vector algebra. I have added an outline of the steps I took to my answer, though. Hopefully that helps a little bit.
